# Why angularJS can't get the input value set by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a script in jQuery that set a text box value :

```
$('.myDropdown li').click(function () {
    var myInput = $(this).data('input');
    $(myInput).val($(this).text());
});
```

[image]

it acts as `select` or `combobox` and i used it for my own reason. It worked perfectly to me but the problem is in my `angularJS`

it cannot read the value of an input set by the jQuery..

Here is my code:

```
$scope.bookFiltering = function () {

        var location = (typeof $scope.bookLocation === "undefined") ? "" : $scope.bookLocation.value.toLowerCase();
        var title = (typeof $scope.bookTitle === "undefined") ? "" : $scope.bookTitle.toLowerCase();

        var callNum = (typeof $scope.bookCallNumber === "undefined") ? "" : $scope.bookCallNumber.toLowerCase();
        var publisher = (typeof $scope.bookPublisher === "undefined") ? "" : $scope.bookPublisher.toLowerCase();
        var subject = (typeof $scope.bookSubject === "undefined") ? "" : $scope.bookSubject.toLowerCase();

        angular.forEach($scope.booksInfo, function (book) {
            var jsonLocation = (book.Location.toLowerCase().indexOf(location) === -1);
            var jsonTitle = (book.Title.toLowerCase().indexOf(title) === -1);
            var jsonCallNum = (book.CallNo.toLowerCase().indexOf(callNum) === -1);
            var jsonPublisher = (book.Publisher.toLowerCase().indexOf(publisher) === -1);
            //var jsonSubject = (book.Subject.indexOf(subject) === -1);

            book.excludeBook = jsonLocation || jsonTitle || jsonCallNum || jsonPublisher;
        });

    };
```

The code is working in fact the other textbox when inputed is read by angular..

and i noticed that when i just type the value in the `input` in my customized select it actually read by angular..

How to make a readable input value in angular using my customized select?

I appreciate for others help.. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting value in hidden element , directly change the value of variable in angular `scope` , Angular wont support the hidden elements